# Is it possible to include temporary script files to be run by postinst in a Debian package?

Tags: debian, packaging

I want to create a Debian package that runs a few scripts in `postinst`. These scripts are only needed in `postinst` (they're just too unwieldy to include in `postinst` itself).

Is there a standard way to have them included and accessible in the installation process and then discarded, or should I simply put them in `/usr/share/package-name/` and run them from there?

---

I decided to put the scripts in `/usr/share/package-name/` and run them there, but I'm still interested in an answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/share/package-name/` is the way to go; packages are made of control files and content and nothing else.

The really complicated setups like `exim4-config`, `ldap-auth-config` and `krb5-config` get their own packages to hold configuration scripts and semi-generated conffiles. Things like ebox are also in large part configuration generators.